# Get Manager name using Sharepoint designer 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I need to get the Manager name using sharepoint designer 2013 workflow. Can anyone please help me to achieve this.

Comment: you can simply use the Lookup Manager for User activity option.

Comment: in 2013 workflows Userprofiles activity is not there as like 2010

Comment: I missed 2013 part. I have updated it in answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013 workflow type we do not have Lookup Manager for User activity. For that SharePoint 2013 workflow you will need to use the Call HTTP Web Service activity, with the following end point URL:

```
http://your-sharepoint-site/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v=[%Workflow Context:Initiator%]
```

You can get more information at [Details](http://spmavericks.com/2014/10/30/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-find-manager-alternative/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use SharePoint 2010 workflow in SharePoint 2013.
Then use lookup Userprofiles activity to get manager name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 2010 workflow then you can select 
Data source as **User profiles**
and select the field as **Manager**

[image]