# Sharepoint 2013 Workflow solution to get manager information

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, workflow

I am converting sharepoint 2010 workflow to 2013. Part of the one 2010 workflow use  find manager information of the user who create an item. But in 2013 its not exists. So I managed to find an article @ stackexchange . with an answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165012/get-manager-name-using-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow)

But the issue is , the link which  is attached to post is not active

In the post says :
http://your-sharepoint-site/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v=[%Workflow Context:Initiator%]

My question:

If i pass the  parameter to [%Workflow Context:Initiator%] (), i get this error message.

I have tried
my domain  username/ email address /i:0#.f|membership|myemail@address.com formats

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">The query string "accountName" is missing or invalid.</m:message>
</m:error>

What am i missing ?

using Sharepoint online/ Foundation

Tx for advice

Answer (score 0):

You can design your workflow like the following:
[image]
The result is:
[image]
More information, you can refer to:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/get-user-profile-properties-data-in-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/